# Polkadot Transaction flow using relaychains and bridges

Tags: polkadot, relay-chain

how to describe the transactional flow of polkadot using relaychains and bridges using sequence diagram describing any usecase can anyone help in doing so...

Answer (score 1):

- Take a look into this blog post [Polkadot Bridges - Connecting the Polkadot Ecosystem with External Networks](https://polkadot.network/blog/polkadot-bridges-connecting-the-polkadot-ecosystem-with-external-networks/)
- The Polkadot Wiki about [bridges](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-bridges)
- An a more concrete example: [Interlay](https://docs.interlay.io/#/getting-started/interbtc) they are building a trustless bridge from Bitcoin to Polkadot.